# How do you save the characters of a file into a string or array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io

For example, if I had a file name random.txt, which reads:

> This is a string.
>   Abc
>   Zxy

How would you save the characters in random.txt to a string or array that includes all of the characters in the text file?

So far I have (using redirection for file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    int c;

    do {
      c = fgetc(stdin);
      putchar(c);
    } while (c != EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First part: About file handles

The `stdin` variable holds a FILE handle to which the user input is redirected (the FILE data type is defined in stdio.h). You can create handles to files using the function `FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)`.

Your example applied to a regular file would be something like this (no error checking is done):

```
int main() {
    int c;
    FILE *myfile = fopen("path/to/file", "r"); //Open file for reading
    while(!feof(myfile)) {
        c = fgetc(myfile);
        //do stuff with 'c'
        //...
    }
    fclose(myfile); //close the file
    return 0;
}
```

More information about `fopen` here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

### Second part: About C strings

C strings (`char` arrays terminated with the null character `'\0'`) can be defined in several ways. One of them is by statically defining them:

```
char mystring[256]; //This defines an array of 256 bytes (255 characters plus end null)
```

It is very important to take care about the limits of the buffer. In our example, writing beyond 256 bytes in the buffer will make the program crash. If we assume our file will not have lines longer than 255 characters (including line terminators like \r and \n) we can use the `fgets` function (http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Simple (newbie) example:

```
int main() {
    char mystring[256];
    FILE *myfile = fopen("path/to/file", "r"); //Open file for reading
    while(!feof(myfile)) {
        if (fgets(mystring, sizeof(mystring), myfile) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", mystring);
        }
    }
    fclose(myfile); //close the file
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that `fgets` is used for reading lines. If you want to read characters 1 by 1, you should keep using `fgetc` and pushing them manually into a buffer.

Finally, if you want to read a whole text file into a C string (no error checking):

```
int main() {
    FILE *myfile = fopen("path/to/file", "r"); //Open file for reading

    //Get the file size
    fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filesize = ftell(myfile);
    fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate buffer dynamically (not statically as in previous examples)
    //We are reserving 'filesize' bytes plus the end null required in all C strings.
    char *mystring = malloc(filesize + 1); //'malloc' is defined in stdlib.h
    fread(mystring, filesize, 1, myfile); //read all file
    mystring[filesize] = 0; //write the end null
    fclose(myfile); //close file
    printf("%s", mystring); //dump contents to screen
    free(mystring); //deallocate buffer. 'mystring' is no longer usable.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c is a integer value, I need to obtain a string value.

Comment: This is C, there's no such thing as a "string value". `fgetc()` gets you characters, the fact they're stored in an `int` is irrelevant.

Comment: As Paul remarks, the "string" concept used in other languages is high-level. In C all you have are arrays of some fixed-size data type. The particular case of an array of 'char' with a final end null is what is known as "C string".

Answer (score 0):

The following will work on either stdin or an actual file (i.e. you can replace "stream" with stdin, or fopen() it with a filename), dynamically allocating as it goes. After it runs, "ptr" will be a pointer to an array holding the contents of the file.

```
/* read chars from stream in blocks of 4096 bytes,
 dynamically allocating until eof */
size_t bytes_read = 0;
char * ptr = NULL;

while (1) {
    size_t chunk_read;
    /* increase size of allocation by 4096 bytes */
    ptr = realloc(ptr, bytes_read + 4096);

    /* read up to 4096 bytes to the newest portion of allocation */
    chunk_read = fread(ptr + bytes_read, 1, 4096, stream);
    bytes_read += chunk_read;

    /* if fread() got less than the full amount of characters, break */
    if (chunk_read < 4096) break;
}

/* resize pointer downward to actual number of bytes read,
 plus an explicit null termination */
bytes_read += 1;
ptr = realloc(ptr, bytes_read);
ptr[bytes_read - 1] = '\0';
```